# PHP - Getting MSSQL to work on Windows 10

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to connect to a MSSQL server via PHP on Windows 10. But I running into some major problems getting the following error:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )
```

I am asked to install Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. But this driver is not compatible with Windows 10. I have installed the PHP drivers for PHP 7 and PHP 5. Neither will work without  Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server, but this is not compatible with Windows 10.

Has anyone found a way round this? I have tried to download this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=36434

But it is incompatible with Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to find, but the Version you need to support most recent stuff and Windows 10 is

**MS ODBC Driver 13**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420

Comment: I have downloaded that but it is incompatible with Windows 10. :( @DanFromGermany

Comment: Thanks for this @DanFromGermany, but I am still getting the same error This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.

Comment: Haha XD, sorry I should be more clear. I can install the drivers now. But I am getting the PHP error saying that I don't have the drivers.